# ffmpeg; video duration is longer than the actual recording time

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I'm using the following command to record the screen with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -video_size 720x878 -framerate 24 -f x11grab -i :0.0+720,0 -vf setpts=N/FR/TB -vcodec libx264 -y -loglevel quiet output.mkv &
```

Also I'm using the following commands to pause, resume and stop the recording:

```bash
# to pause
pkill -STOP ffmpeg 

#to resume
pkill -CONT ffmpeg

# to stop
pkill -INT ffmpeg
```

I noticed that the total time of the recording is longer than the actual time that it took to record the video. Simply put, the output is longer than expected to be.

To test my understanding, I ran the following loop that prints elapsed time every second and then I recorded it for about one minute.

```
i=1 && while true; do echo $((i++)) && sleep 1; done

# example output
1
2
3
...
```

Whenever I resume the recording, new echos come slightly slower than a second and it lasts for about 4 to 5 seconds, then everything goes back to normal. Actually each echo then corresponds to one second. So I thought that maybe its encoding/decoding that takes time.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: How much longer? That's an important piece of information. After considering buffers/caches, the accuracy of your sleeps and even the type of encoding, this could be normal behaviour.

Comment: Why `-vf setpts=N/FR/TB`?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani What do you mean by accuracy of sleeps? I tried other encodings such as `huffyuv`, `mpeg2video`, `mpeg4` and even `rawvideo` with no success. I told after *resuming* a paused video each second is slightly longer, maybe a half of a second and this lasts for 4 to 5 seconds.

Comment: @Gyan Sending a -STOP signal didn't pause the recording. So I searched for a solution and came up with the steps filter.